# Infinite loops in Python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

So I have two python threads running from inside a class. I have checked using

```
threading.active_count()
```

and it says both threads are running. The first thread includes a tkinter window which works fine. The second thread I am using as an event manager for the first window, which also works okay by itself. However, when I run the second thread alongside the first thread, the first thread does not work, ie. the window does not appear. This is even if the first thread is executed first. When I remove the infinite loop from the second thread, the first thread works again, can anyone explain this to me? Here is the class:

```
class Quiz(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    def show(self, question):
        self.question = quiz[question][0]
        self.correct = quiz[question][1]
        self.incorrectA = quiz[question][2]
        self.incorrectB = quiz[question][3]
        self.ref = quiz[question][4]
        questionDisplay.config(text=self.question)
        correctButton = "answer" + str(self.ref[0])
        eval(correctButton).config(text=self.correct, command=lambda : check(True))
        incorrect1 = "answer" + str(self.ref[1])
        eval(incorrect1).config(text=self.incorrectA, command= lambda : check(False))
        incorrect2 = "answer" + str(self.ref[2])
        eval(incorrect2).config(text=self.incorrectB, command= lambda : check(False))
        return self.correct

    def run(self):
        print("thread started")
        print(threading.active_count())

        while True:
            print(questionQueue.qsize())
            if questionQueue.qsize() >= 1:
                pass

            else:
                pass
            print("looped")
```

Thanks

Comment: If anyone needs anymore of the code just tell me

Comment: Quick point: since your class will inherit `__init__` from `threading.thread` if you don't define it, you might as well omit that method from your definition.

Comment: Generally speaking, tkinter doesn't support threads. It can be done as long as the GUI only runs in the main thread and all interaction with others it done through locks to control concurrent access to data and/or thread-safe data structures like queues.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been doing this long, how would you add locks, and what data would you need to control? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the code as currently shown it is not obvious where the problem lies. But keep the following in mind;

Tk is event-driven like basically all GUI toolkits. So for the GUI to work you need to run Tk's `mainloop`. The only pieces of your code that it runs in the main loop are the various callbacks attached to things like buttons, menus and timers.

Like most GUI toolkits Tk isn't thread-safe because of the overhead that would require. To keep it working properly, you should only call Tk functions and methods from *one* thread.

Python's threads are operating system threads. This means they are subject to operating system scheduling. And the OS sometimes gives more time to threads that are busy. So if a thread that is spinning in a busy-loop is pre-empted (as is done regularly), chances are that it ends up being run again instead of the GUI thread.

Comment: Would I be able to add the window construction to the same thread as the  show() method? Or Could it be done in the __init__() method? It's just I don't think I can add window construction to the same method as show() because show() changes aspects of the window, and probably will be needed to however I write the code

Comment: There is little if any reason to build a class for it anyway. Keep it simple. Create a function to run in the second thread, and create the widgets and run the `mainloop` in the main thread.